# How to Mock NserviceBus SendLocal using Moq

Tags: nservicebus

> context.Verify throws exception: object reference not set to the instance of the object

```
var context = new Mock<IMessagehandlerContext>();

context.Setup(x => x.SendLocal(It.IsAny<object>()))
.Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

context.Verify(b => b.SendLocal(It.IsAny<objec>()), Times.Exactly(1))
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? As it stands the test will never pass. Is there more code you are not posting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking IMessageHandlerContext, I'd suggest you use TestableMessageHandlerContext from NServiceBus.Testing nuget package. Checkout the documentation [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/testing/) .

A sample of how to use it is as follows:

```
[Test]
public async Task ShouldReplyWithResponseMessage()
{
  var handler = new MyReplyingHandler();
  var context = new TestableMessageHandlerContext();

  await handler.Handle(new MyRequest(), context)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

  Assert.AreEqual(1, context.RepliedMessages.Length);
  Assert.IsInstanceOf<MyResponse>(context.RepliedMessages[0].Message);
}
```